# Error when using SHA256 via spring in xml config

Tags: spring, sha256

I'm trying to use java.security.MessageDigest with spring like so.

Bean definition...

```
    <spring:bean id="messageDigest" name="messageDigest" class="java.security.MessageDigest" factory-method="getInstance">
        <spring:constructor-arg value="${hash.algorithm}"/>
    </spring:bean>
```

And this is me using the bean...

```
<invoke name="invokeMessageDigestDigest" object-ref="messageDigest" method="digest" methodArguments="#[flowVars.myCustomTextOne]" methodArgumentTypes="byte[]" />
```

This works for me.

The problem is as soon as I try to use this somewhere else in my application like so....

```
<invoke name="invokeMessageDigestDigest" object-ref="messageDigest" method="digest" methodArguments="#[flowVars.myCustomTextTwo]" methodArgumentTypes="byte[]" />
```

I get ...

```
Failed to instantiate [java.security.MessageDigest]: Factory method 'getInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256 MessageDigest not available
```

I tried to add some magic to the bean definition using scope=prototype because I was thinking it might have something funny to do with bean instantiation but this did not fix the issue.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct name of the algorithm is `SHA-256` as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest. SHA256 is just an alias provided by the Bouncycastle library